# How to get Camel Websocket component to send message upon connection from client?

Tags: java, websocket, apache-camel

I have created a working Camel Websocket route using the Java DSL, but I cannot figure out how to get Camel to trigger an event when a new client connects so that I can then send out an initialization message to the client...

```
    LOG.info("ReplicationSink route is loading");
    String uri = "websocket://0.0.0.0:2081/v3/replication";
    boolean interest_sent = false;
    onException(AccessDeniedException.class)
            .handled(true)
            .transform()
            .simple("{\"error\": \"Access Denied\", \"message\":\"${exception.message}\"}")
            .to(uri);
    from(uri)   // How can I specify here that upon initial connection to send the INTEREST_MESSAGE?
            .log(DEBUG, "replication-sink", simple("${body}").getText())
            .choice()
            .when().simple("${header.interested} == null")
                .log(DEBUG, "Preparing to send interest message")
                .setBody().constant(INTEREST_MESSAGE)
                .setHeader("interested").constant("true")
                .to(uri)
            .when().simple("${header.qfor} == null")
                .log(DEBUG, "Setting QFOR headers")
                .setHeader("data").body()
                .setHeader("qfor").constant("TEST")
                .setHeader("self").javaScript("JSON.parse(request.body).self")
                .to(uri)
            .otherwise()
                .log(DEBUG, "Receiving updates")
                .setBody(simple("INSERT INTO raw (qfor, self, data) VALUES (:?qfor, :?self, :?data::jsonb)"))
                .to("jdbc:ccindexer?useHeadersAsParameters=true");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afaik, I don't think it's possible in the current version of Camel.

A workaround:

- Configure the websocket component to use your own WebSocketFactory. This factory should extend `DefaultWebSocketFactory` and should be registered under the protocol 'default' (ie see `WebSocketComponent.setSocketFactory`)
- In your implementation of `WebSocketFactory`, return your own implementation of `WebSocket`,  extending `DefaultWebSocket`
- In your implementation of WebSocket, you have then access to the method `onOpen` and the associated `Connection` (with `Connection.sendMessage`)

Comment: OK, this was the right answer to get me going down the right path... Took a little digging around to figure it out, but this helped immensely!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem some time ago, came to the same conclusion as above and I created an implementation. Code is Apache licence and can be found here:
https://github.com/SignalK/signalk-server-java/tree/master/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/websocket

You will have to work back up to find the way its used - look for the RouteManager.class